# Video Header in 2016 theme

Tags: headers

I am using 2016 WordPress theme I have customized theme and added header media option in the customise dashboard. I can add video in the header but it's not showing up on the front page. Wordpress 5.0.3 is running on 2016 theme. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at is_front_page (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Comment: Thanks @LucienDubois for the comment, but I am using my home page as static only. And header video only display on home page and it does in my case too. I can see the the placeholder for video header but cant see the video itself. Please find this scrrenshot https://prnt.sc/mee87m

Comment: Ok! Any errors in the console ? Is it a mp4 file ?

Comment: no errors in console...i followed and checked again all the steps for adding custom headers from this link - https://napitwptech.com/tutorial/wordpress-development/display-header-video-in-wordpress-in-different-pages/

Comment: yes, its mp4 file

Comment: I am also getting the same problem in 2019 theme. Only 2017 is working fine with Header Media